# Why can I not remove the _id key from the results of my .find() query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a query which looks as such:

```
collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).toArray((err, result) => {
  io.sockets.connected[clients[client.length-1]].emit('update chart state', result);
});
```

My websocket is sending the data correctly to the client however the `_id` field is still present in the array of objects that I receive. Could someone point out to me what I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: For the NodeJs driver I believe you will need to issue the projection as a call to the cursor returned via `find`, e.g., `colleciton.find({}).project({_id: 0}).toArray(...)` It looks like you're using shell syntax. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/projections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`find`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) function takes only one parameter - the query. The returned value is a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html), which contains a [`project`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) function. You can, therefore, use something like this:

```
collection.find({}).project({_id: 0}).toArray ...
```